# calling a function is changing code that has nothing to do with it

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

I have a list (aList) who's data gets replaced by (bList) after a function is called. I've put comments in the first function that show where the data gets changed

I know it has something to do with the tempList.Clear() that runs at the beginning of sub_split, because if i comment it out, aList doesn't get overwritten. The problem is that I put it there, because for some reason if i directly append the new strings to rList instead of running it through tempList first, the program kind of freezes up... so a few things going wrong and I'm pretty stuck.

```
#global variables:
cList = []
tempList = []


def substrings(a, b, n):

    seen.clear()
    """Return substrings of length n in both a and b"""

    aList = []
    bList = []
    cList = []

    n = int(n)
    aList = sub_split(a, aList, n)
    print(aList) # <- prints correctly
    bList = sub_split(b, bList, n)
    print(aList) # <- now prints bList instead


    if len(aList) < len(bList):
        compareLines(aList, bList)

    else:
       # print(aList)
        compareLines(bList, aList)

    return cList


def sub_split(text, rList, n):
    #split into lines first
    tempList.clear()
    rList = lineSplitter(text, rList)
    for strings in rList:
        for i in range(len(strings)):
            tempList.append(strings[i:n+i])

    rList = tempList
    return rList


def lineSplitter(text, rList):
    with open(text, "r") as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()
        for line in lines:
           line = line.strip()
           rList.append(line)

        return rList
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what is wrong. Please make it more clear - explain what you're expecting and what you're getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a big chain of lists that all point to each other.

Essentially what you have is the following:

```
>>> tempList = []
>>> rList = []
>>> aList = []
>>> rList = tempList
>>> aList = rList
```

Now when I change `tempList`, `aList` also gets updated because it points to `tempList`

```
>>> tempList.append(1)
>>> aList
[1]
```

Rather than having a global `tempList` that you clear every time, just create a new templist in your `sub_split` function:

```
def sub_split(text, rList, n):
    #split into lines first
    tempList = []
```

That way rList points to a completely new list.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I thought it was just copying the data over, not pointing to the same data.